# How to label the tokens as positive or negative

Tags: nlp

I was trying to analyze of cutomer reviews. I have divided it into a list of tokens, How can I label them which token is positive or negative? Is there any library?

I want to build a word cloud of the positive words and negative words.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try many stuffs here (However people usually classify the review as whole in not the words):

- Try Brown clustering to cluster your words, then if you have labels you can better assess the quality of the word clustering.
- Create label for words depending on the label of the review where they are (positive or negative), however this may not be accurate cause negativity is sometime a composition of words (e.k not like).
- ou can also use your labels to derive negative and positive words by their frequencies in negative and positive documents.

There are plenty of libraries to do sentiment classification : scikit-learn,TensorFlow,....ect.